# p:nth-child(even) and p:nth-child(odd) losing count with intermediate div's placed after a few <p>'s

Tags: css-selectors

`p:nth-child(even)` and `p:nth-child(odd)` losing count with intermediate 's placed after a few `<p>`'s

Here is what I've got:

```
p:nth-child(even) {
    
    font-style: italic;
}

<p> text </p>
<p> more text <//p>
<p> and still more text <//p>
<div> stuff </div>
<p> text </p>
<p> more text <//p>
```

Starts out great: italic, plain, italic, plain, plain

The intermediate `<div> stuff </div>` resets everything.

**???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably want the functionality of `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child` based on what you're describing.  Article on the difference here https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/

Your example: https://jsfiddle.net/nh16ytq7/